# How to get particular text from a string using robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I need to get the number before ':' from a string using robotframework how can I do it?

```
${str}=    Set Variable  7939:customer-Id:123a34ghas
```

I need to get only **7939** before ':' how can I do it in the robot framework?

```
${Id}=   split string ${str}
log to console   ${Id} #Should give only 7939
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
${str}=    Set Variable    7939:customer-Id:123a34ghas

${Id}=    split string    ${str}    :

log to console    ${Id}[0]    #prints 7939
```

Comment: Please always format code, especially here with RF, it I just copy your example/solution, it won't work.